# What is the best way to remove asbestos tiles?

Tags: tile, removal, asbestos

What is the best way to remove old asbestos tile?

Comment: If you want to do it properly and safely, you might find that it's actually cheaper to hire somebody to handle it. However, that's going to completely depend on the companies in your area.  Might be worth a few phone calls though.

Comment: Depends on the kind of tile and it's condition. And on whether there is also asbestos in the adhesive. Laying a floating floor over the tile may be a better option.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Home Improvement Stack Exchange. A little more information and possibly a photo would be helpful.

The first thing to do is make sure you have a facility that will accept the waste. Some landfills will not take asbestos.

Next a high end respirator with replaceable filter cartridges. In most cases a garden sprayer filled with water to moisten and reduce any dust when removing. I use a [floor stripper like this](http://www.homedepot.com/s/Floor%2520Scrapers%2520%2526%2520Strippers?NCNI-5) to pop tiles.

The clean-up teams I have worked with in the past wore Tyvek jump suits, rubber gloves and boots. You will want to make sure to block all the vents into the room and seal the doorways to prevent any dust from getting into the rest of the house.

Answer (score 0):

Advice I got from a pro was, if the tiles were in good condition and not releasing any fibers, I could use a heat gun to warm them enough to soften the adhesive and carefully lift them intact with a putty knife.

However, the adhesive may also contain asbestos, and if so that's a lot harder to remove.

He suggested simply encapsulating the problem under a floating floor might be a better answer.